# Autocomplete text with logos

Tags: android, arraylist, autocomplete

Is it possible to get suggestions of autocomplete text with the icons?I done with autocomplete text using adapters but i want icons for each so that it looks better.could you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in this tutorial

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-autocompletetextview-to-display-images-and-text-in-the-suggestion-list-using-simpleadapter-in-android/

I think it will help you